# How do I remove portion of each line from "@" to "|" in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

How do I remove portion of each line from "@" to "|" in notepad++

```
apple@oranges.com|cake to apple|cake
```

Comment: Which `|` character do you want to match?

Answer (score 2):

Like heavyd suggested, it depends which `|` you want to match.

DBZ_A's solution will give you the greedy (as long as possible) match.

This will give you the lazy (shorter) match, which I suspect you want

Find what: `@[^\|]*\|`

(This should match an `@`, followed by any number of characters that are *not* `|`, followed by `|`)

Replace with: `@|`

Comment: @Scott Er, yes, that's right. I was just testing you. Good work. (answer updated)

Answer (score 1):

Use 'Regular expression' option in find and replace dialogue

search for :

> @(.*)\|

replace with:

> @|

Note that the | character needs to be escaped as \| in the search string